# Recursively generate hierarchy for any given node in the tree?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

This CTE fetches the hierarchy of `SuiteID`s and `ParentSuiteID`s as the result set below. I want to pass the `SuiteID` and all `SuiteID`s that are parents with their respective level.

```
WITH HIERARCHY AS
( select T1.SuiteID,T1.Title,T1.ParentSuiteID, 0 Level 
  FROM tbl_Suite(nolock) T1
  Where T1.ParentSuiteID = 0 AND T1.PlanID = '404'
  UNION ALL
  select T2.SuiteID,T2.Title,T2.ParentSuiteID,Level+1 
  from tbl_Suite(nolock) AS T2
  INNER JOIN HIERARCHY AS H ON T2.ParentSuiteID = H.SuiteID
)

SELECT * 
FROM HIERARCHY
```

```
    +---------+------------------------+---------------+-------+
    | SuiteID |         Title          | ParentSuiteID | Level |
    +---------+------------------------+---------------+-------+
    |   10664 | root                   |             0 |     0 |
    |   10681 | Prod Test Environment  |         10664 |     1 |
    |   11097 | Dev Test Environment   |         10664 |     1 |
    |   11155 | Training Environment   |         10664 |     1 |
    |   11156 | Production Environment |         10664 |     1 |
    |   11100 | Bridge PMS             |         11097 |     2 |
    |   11126 | Bridge PTS             |         11097 |     2 |
    |   11139 | Client 360             |         11097 |     2 |
    |   11140 | Contact Manager        |         11097 |     2 |
    |   11145 | Revenue DashBoard      |         11097 |     2 |
    |   11141 | Finance flow           |         11140 |     3 |
    |   11142 | Premium Finance flow   |         11140 |     3 |
    |   11143 | Client Contacts        |         11140 |     3 |
    |   11127 | Direct Bill            |         11126 |     3 |
    +---------+------------------------+---------------+-------+
```

I want to write a query that gives the following resultset when I pass (SuiteID = 11100):

```
SuiteID Title                      ParentSuiteID    Level 
10664   root                        0                  0
11097   Dev Test Environment        10664              1
11100   Bridge PMS                  11097              2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @Table table (SuiteID  int,Title varchar(50),ParentSuiteID int)
Insert into @Table values 
(10664 ,'root                   ',    0),
(10681 ,'Prod Test Environment  ',10664 ),
(11097 ,'Dev Test Environment   ',10664 ),
(11155 ,'Training Environment   ',10664 ),
(11156 ,'Production Environment ',10664 ),
(11100 ,'Bridge PMS'             ,11097 )


Declare @Fetch int = 11100   

;with cteHB as (
      Select SuiteID 
            ,ParentSuiteID
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Title 
      From   @Table 
      Where  SuiteID =@Fetch
      Union  All
      Select R.SuiteID 
            ,R.ParentSuiteID
            ,P.Lvl+1
            ,R.Title 
      From   @Table R
      Join   cteHB P on P.ParentSuiteID = R.SuiteID )
Select Lvl = Row_Number() over (Order By Lvl Desc) -1
      ,SuiteID 
      ,ParentSuiteID
      ,Title
From cteHB
Order By 1
```

Returns

```
Lvl SuiteID ParentSuiteID   Title
0   10664   0               root                   
1   11097   10664           Dev Test Environment   
2   11100   11097           Bridge PMS
```

Comment: Thank you John, just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Sharktooth Happy it helped